# PHP: How to set value into empty index in an Array?

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

I have array in my PHP, for example:

#### array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array 
        (
           [0] => 
           [1] => 
           [2] => 
           [3] => 
           [4] => 
           [5] => Grape
           [6] => Apple 
           [7] => Pineaple
           [8] => Avocado
           [9] => Banana
        )
)
```

and I need to fill the empty element (index `0` upto `4`) with new value from an `array` or `$variable`.
Maybe for example, I get the data from another `array`:

#### newArray

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array 
        (
           [0] => Lemon
           [1] => Lime
           [2] => Mango
           [3] => Watermelon
           [4] => Starfruit
        )
)
```

so I can get a result like this:

#### finalArray

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array 
        (
           [0] => Lemon
           [1] => Lime
           [2] => Mango
           [3] => Watermelon
           [4] => Starfruit
           [5] => Grape
           [6] => Apple 
           [7] => Pineaple
           [8] => Avocado
           [9] => Banana
        )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Simply loop and check if empty and set the value.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @SougataBose I've loop and check, but I'm  not sure which method or function to set the value.

Comment: @Naga I've tried to use array_fill and array_combine but I didn't get result as my expectation.

Comment: did you try `array_merge`? It may help you.

Comment: @Naga I've tried, but `array_merge` set into new element, it didn't set into empty element. But the answer below has been solved this problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [loop through your array](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php/), check if the index is empty and then, set it's value.

```
<?php
foreach($array as $index=>$value)
{
  if(empty($array[$index]))
  {
    $array[$index] = $newValue;
  }

}
```

Comment: It's work :) foreach is the best way to do that. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array=array("0"=>"","1"=>"","2"=>"","5"=>"Grape","6"=>"Apple","7"=>"Pineaple","8"=>"Avocado","9"=>"Banana");
echo "<pre>";print_r($array);echo"</pre>";
$newarray= array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if($value == ''){
        //echo $key."<br>";
        $value = 'Somevalue';
    }
    $newarray[] = $value;
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($value);echo"</pre>";
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($newarray);echo"</pre>";
?>
```

[Link](https://eval.in/705762)

Comment: It's work! Thanks, you right, foreach is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a function in a standard library called [`array_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php). If the new values in the other array have the same indices you can use it:

```
$result = array_replace($array1, $array2);
```

If you just need to set up default values for empty elements use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$defaultValue = 'Foo';
$result = array_map(function ($item) use ($defaultValue) {
    return $item ?: $defaultValue;
}, $array1);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e7cc6ce7a94398d2c642c35f1c701c528c4c5ce).

Comment: @Archibald, you are welcome. If you like it, then, please, upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Use only `array_merge()` function
For Example

```
 print_r( array_merge($array, $newarray) );
```

Comment: `array_merge` set the data into new element, it didn't set into empty element